# .Net Unit Testing: Map TestMethods to corresponding implementation methods for navigation purposes

Tags: .net, unit-testing, tdd

On a project I'm working on, we're developing in a test-driven way (TDD). We're building various layers of abstraction and testing each one separately, using mocks for the lower-layer dependencies where appropriate.

As a result, we usually end up having a small handful of concise unit tests (TestMethods) for each method in a target class.

I often find myself looking at the implementation of a method and wanting to see a list of the unit test TestMethods that test it. Normally I just do a 'find all usages' on the method name to get a list of the corresponding unit tests (among all the other usages in the solution).

My question: is there any metadata that can be used on a TestMethod (like an attribute or the `<see cref="..."/>` that's used for documentation) that specifies which method it's actually testing? Going one step further: can I then navigate quickly to these test(s) given that I'm in the implementation?

For me, the benefit would purely be in terms of productivity/navigation. (Edit): considering my first comment below, one might argue that such metadata could encourage good design of tests as well as implementations.

We're using Visual Studio 2012 with Resharper 7.

Comment: I imagine such meta-data would give a false sense of cohesion between the tests and the implementation.  What about tests which indirectly use those methods by calling other methods which in turn call the one you're looking at?  Or methods which aren't directly tested at all but are covered by other indirect tests?

Comment: Thanks David. On cohesion: my argument is that such metadata would be interpreted as "this is a test for that method". Such cohesion between a unit test method and an implementation method seems to me to be a natural fit. On your other comments: I'd argue that such metadata would 1) encourage well-designed tests where each test method does its thing concisely WITHOUT needing to call some other testing layer, and 2) encourage well-designed implementations...if I have a method which isn't directly tested then I probably have either nontested functionality or my upper-layer tests are too complex.